# I am using httplib2 and had read that httplib2 handles caching automatically but when I execute 'fromcache' on the response object, it returns false

Tags: web-services, python-3.x, cache-control, httplib2

## This is my code

import httplib2

httplib2.debuglevel = 1

h = httplib2.Http(".cache")

response, content = h.request('http://diveintopython3.org/examples/feed.xml')

print(response.fromcache)

Answer (score 0):

The link(http://diveintopython3.org/examples/feed.xml) I was using in my code is inactive now that why I was facing such issue.

Answer (score 0):

Using a resource that, at time of writing, exists and declares itself cachable:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import httplib2

h = httplib2.Http('cache')

response, content = h.request('https://example.com/')
print(response.status)
print(response.fromcache)

response, content = h.request('https://example.com/')
print(response.status)
print(response.fromcache)
```

Gives:

```
200
False
200
True
```

on the first run, indicating that both requests were successful, and that the second was served from the cache. Running it again gives:

```
200
True
200
True
```

as the cache is persisted on disk from the previous run.